# Spring cloud gateway - io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I am using below stack

Spring Cloud Gateway Hoxton Release,
Java 1.8,
Linux OS

I am seeing below exception which goes away after a restart but again shows up after some time. I have not done any explicit settings for direct memory. Below are the JVM arguments used -

```
-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10240K -Xloggc:logs/gc.log0423_0751 -verbose:gc -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=logs -XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=false
```

Could anyone advise what could be the reason for error?

```
[2020-04-22 05:49:11,705] [4faa34069d05eede] [668067318] [reactor-http-epoll-3] [ERROR] [o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler] - [b9f747ab]  500 Server Error
for HTTP GET "/lmp/user"
io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 503316487, max: 5189
79584)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/lmp/user" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
                at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:107)
                at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:348)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:708)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1700(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:56)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1102)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1149)
                at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1073)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
                at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:413)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
                at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 503316487, max: 518979584)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:726)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:681)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:758)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:734)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:245)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:215)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:147)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:342)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:115)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectEncoder.encode(HttpObjectEncoder.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Encoder.encode(HttpClientCodec.java:167)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:708)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1700(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:56)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1149)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1073)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:413)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems issue was with a filter which was logging the response body in a log file using code like below

```
return new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(origResponse) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                if (body instanceof Flux) {
                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                    return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map(dataBuffer -> {
                        byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                        dataBuffer.read(content);
                        String bodyContent = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        GatewayJsonLogger.log(null, exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath(), bodyContent, "RESPONSE");
                        return bufferFactory.wrap(content);
                        
                    }));
                }
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }
        };
```

The DataBuffer was not being released. Below is the revised code which fixed the issue

```
return new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(origResponse) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                if (body instanceof Flux) {
                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                    return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map(dataBuffer -> {
                        try{
                        byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                        dataBuffer.read(content);
                        String bodyContent = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        GatewayJsonLogger.log(null, exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath(), bodyContent, "RESPONSE");
                        return bufferFactory.wrap(content);
                        } finally {
                            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer); 
                        }
                    }));
                }
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }
        };
```